# get Date in specific format from sqlserver 2012

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012, date-conversion

I have a table named `NewsMaster` which has a column named `NewsDate` .

Date is stored as `2016-05-19 00:00:00.000` in this table.

Now i want to retrieve this date as something like **October-2016** . that's it. looked so many blogs but nothing found.

```
DATENAME(month,GETDATE()) 'Month Name'
```

is this helpful? am i close? need modification.

Comment: FORMAT() or DATENAME(MONTH, col) + '-' + DATENAME(YEAR, col)

Comment: Can U please describe more?

Comment: `SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, NewsDate) + '-' + DATENAME(YEAR, NewsDate)  FROM NewsMaster`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select DATENAME(month,GETDATE())+' - '+ convert(nvarchar,DATEPART(yyyy,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) function introduced in sql server 2012.
Try this -

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2016-05-19' AS DATE), 'MMM-yyyy')
```

**Result**

```
May-2016
```

You can use it in your query like this -

```
SELECT FORMAT(NewsDate, 'MMM-yyyy') AS NewsDate FROM yourTable
```

Comment: my column name is NewsDate

Comment: 'FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. this is the error in your query

Comment: @DinavAhire: Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2012 ? check your instance\